# imprimir nodos hojas de un árbol binario c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, codeblocks

Este es el código que quiero utilizar para imprimir las hojas de un árbol binario, quiero que se impriman todos los nodos hijos (que no tengan nada ni por la derecha ni por la izq) que se encuentren a la izquierda de un nodo padre.

Esa función me imprime todos los nodos hojas y he intentado de todo.

```
struct adivinador{
    string objeto;
    struct adivinador *izq;
    struct adivinador *der;

    adivinador(string ob){
        objeto = ob;
        izq = NULL;
        der= NULL;
    }

}*raiz;

void animalesIzquierda(struct adivinador *raiz){
    if ( raiz== NULL)
        return;

    struct adivinador *prov= raiz;

    if((raiz->izq == NULL) and (raiz->der == NULL)){
        cout<<prov->objeto<<", ";
        }
    animalesIzquierda(raiz->izq);
    animalesIzquierda(raiz->der);
}
```

Comment: Una sujerencia. Incluye en el código la estructura **struct adivinador** y la forma en la que estás dando valores a los nodos para que podamos ver mas ampliamente lo que estás haciendo.

Answer (score 0):

La idea de hacer esto es similar al algoritmo DFS. A continuación, se muestra un algoritmo paso a paso para hacer esto:

Compruebe si el nodo dado es nulo. Si es nulo, regrese de la función.
Verifica si es un nodo hoja. Si el nodo es un nodo hoja, imprima sus datos.
Si en el paso anterior, el nodo no es un nodo hoja, verifique si existen secundarios izquierdos y derechos del nodo. Si es así, llame a la función para secundarios izquierdo y derecho del nodo de forma recursiva.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


{
    int data;
    struct Node *left, *right;
};



void printLeafNodes(Node *root)
{
    // if node is null, return
    if (!root)
        return;

    // if node is leaf node, print its data    
    if (!root->left && !root->right)
    {
        cout << root->data << " "; 
        return;
    }


    if (root->left)
       printLeafNodes(root->left);


    if (root->right)
       printLeafNodes(root->right);
} 


Node* newNode(int data)
{
    Node *temp = new Node;
    temp->data = data;
    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    return temp;
}


int main()
{

    Node *root = newNode(1);
    root->left = newNode(2);
    root->right = newNode(3);
    root->left->left = newNode(4);
    root->right->left = newNode(5);
    root->right->right = newNode(8);
    root->right->left->left = newNode(6);
    root->right->left->right = newNode(7);
    root->right->right->left = newNode(9);
    root->right->right->right = newNode(10);


    printLeafNodes(root);

    return 0;
}
```